# Blazor Page added to existing standard .NET MAUI app is not scrolling

Tags: maui

I have a standard .NET MAUI app targeting .NET 7 and using XAML for UI. I want to continue with this approach but also want to have a few Blazor pages in the app.

I've already implemented this following the steps below and it actually works fine. The problem I seem to be having is that the Blazor page is not scrolling. I purposely put a lot of text on the page and I can only see what fits the screen and it's not responding to my swipes. What do I need to do to make sure the Blazor page is scrollable?

Here are the exact steps I've taken:

1. Changed the SDK in proj file from `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">`
2. Added `wwwroot` folder containing `css` and `index.html` files
3. Created a folder named `Pages` which is where I intend to keep all my Blazor pages
4. Placed `Shared` folder containing `MainLayout.razor` in the `Pages` folder -- again to keep everything Blazor in one place
5. Created `MyTestComponent.razor` in `Pages` folder

It's important to note that I left out the `Main.razor` because I don't want to handle any routing through Blazor. I simply want to place `BlazorWebView` in my regular .NET MAUI pages using XAML and handle my navigation through the Shell.

The `BlazorWebView` code on my `ContentPage` looks like this i.e. pointing directly at my component:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages.Testing"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent
                    Selector="#app"
                    ComponentType="{x:Type page:MyTestComponent}"/>
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Looks like I made a mistake somewhere or left something out. Any suggestions on how to fix the scroll issue on the Blazor page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause should be you put the **BlazorWebView** into the **VerticalStackLayout**.

You can try the default the style(**delete the VerticalStackLayout**) :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages.Testing"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
        <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent
                    Selector="#app"
                    ComponentType="{x:Type page:MyTestComponent}"/>
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

Or you can put it into the ScrollView:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages.Testing"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent
                    Selector="#app"
                    ComponentType="{x:Type page:MyTestComponent}"/>
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Yup! Removing the `VerticalStackLayout` fixed the issue. Thank you!